# can adapterview be used for intent call in android

Tags: android

I am trying to run the following code , it was running in previous version of android studio but not in latest version, what is wrong

error shown in line -->adapterview = new Intent(this,Class.forName("com.project.hdl.hdl.inputfile")); is incompatible types where inputfile is a java class

```
{ public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterview, View view, int i, long l)
{
    itemname = verilogArray[i];
    try
    {
        adapterview = new Intent(this,Class.forName("com.project.hdl.hdl.inputfile"));
        adapterview.putExtra("itemName", (new StringBuilder("verilog/")).append(itemname).toString());
        startActivity(adapterview);
        return;
    }
    // Misplaced declaration of an exception variable
    catch (AdapterView adapterview)
    {
        adapterview.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace from your Logcat

Comment: Problem synopsis      Unchecked call to 'ArrayAdapter(Context, int, T[])' as a member of raw type 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter' (at line 32)